# Weird situation for typescript

Tags: typescript

I am learning Typescript and have a question.
I tried to make function in typescript.

This is example of function.

```
test() {
    let i: number[] = [];
    console.log(i);

    i[0] = 1;
    i[1] = 2;
    i[2] = 3;
}
```

In this case, the result is [1, 2, 3]
How does it works? I tried to print `i` before set up the value of array.
I expected to print only this `[]`. 
Please anybody explain about this?

thank you in advance.

Comment: ^ That. Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(i))` and you'll see it is indeed `[]` at that point. The JS console otherwise has a real reference to the array.